# I would like to add a behaviour to a specific icon tapped

Tags: android, dart, flutter

```
bottomNavigationBar: new Material(

    color: Colors.green,
    child: new TabBar(

        controller: controller,
        tabs: <Widget>[




          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.filter_center_focus),),
          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.search),),

        ],


        ),
  ),
```

I would like to add a specific function for each icon tapped. Something like (onPressed() {} ,or onTap(){}

Comment: Thank you. Well I didn't know I could call it "card" Mr.